# .mkv Videos are lagging in textureview

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, surfaceview, android-videoview, android-textureview

I used Textureview with mediaplayer for playing videos.Its working fine for .3gp and .mp4 video types.But its lagging much for .mkv videos.I tried with videoview and surfaceview with mediaplayer.still the problem persists.if anyone having a solution for my issues pls help.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

have a look on [Exoplayer](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/exoplayer.html) it is an alternative solution for playing videos in different extension.